# Using React.setState in componentDidMount() for data returned within nested promises?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I'm trying to put some data into state in a React app.  The flow involves fetching a list of IDs from the HackerNews API, then taking each ID and making an additional API call to fetch the item associated with each ID.  I ultimately want to have an array of 50 items in my component state (the resulting value of the each '2nd-level' fetch.

When I setState from JUST the single 'top-level' promise/API call, it works fine and my state is set with an array of IDs.  When I include a second `.then()` API call and try to map over a series of subsequent API calls, my state gets set with unresolved Promises, then the `fetch()` calls are made.

[image: devtools screenshot]

I'm sure this a problem with my poor grasp on building appropriate async methods.

*Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong, and what the best practice for this is??*

**My component:**

```js
import React from 'react'
import { fetchStoryList } from '../utils/api'

export default class Stories extends React.Component {
  state = {
    storyType: 'top',
    storyList: null,
    error: null,
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    let { storyType } = this.state

    fetchStoryList(storyType)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("data", data)
        this.setState({ storyList: data })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.warn('Error fetching stories: ', error)

        this.setState({
          error: `There was an error fetching the stories.`
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.storyList)}</pre>
    )
  }
}
```

**My API Interface:**

```js
// HackerNews API Interface

function fetchStoryIds (type = 'top') {
  const endpoint = `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/${type}stories.json`

  return fetch(endpoint)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((storyIds) => {
      if(storyIds === null) {
        throw new Error(`Cannot fetch ${type} story IDs`)
      }

      return storyIds
    })
}

function fetchItemById(id) {
  const endpoint = `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}.json`

  return fetch(endpoint)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((item) => item)
}

export function fetchStoryList (type) {
  return fetchStoryIds(type)
    .then((idList) => idList.slice(0,50))
    .then((idList) => {
      return idList.map((id) => {
        return fetchItemById(id)
      })
    })
//ABOVE CODE WORKS WHEN I COMMENT OUT THE SECOND THEN STATEMENT
```

Comment: If you change the name of the returned value in the 2nd .then() to something like `slicedIdList` so that it differs from the upper scope, do you continue to run in to this problem? Make sure you're changing the value for the map as well.

Comment: `fetchItemById` returns a Promise that you are not waiting for - try `return Promise.all(idList.map((id) => {
        return fetchItemById(id)
      }))` or for more concise code ... `.then(idList => Promise.all(idList.map(id => fetchItemById(id)));`

Comment: Not a problem, but also `.then((item) => item)` is redundant, remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not waiting for some asynchronous code to "finish"

i.e.

```
.then((idList) => {
  return idList.map((id) => {
    return fetchItemById(id)
  })
})
```

returns returns an array of promises that you are not waiting for

To fix, use Promise.all

(also cleaned up code removing redundancies)

```
function fetchStoryIds (type = 'top') {
    const endpoint = `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/${type}stories.json`;

    return fetch(endpoint)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((storyIds) => {
        if(storyIds === null) {
            throw new Error(`Cannot fetch ${type} story IDs`);
        }
        return storyIds;
    });
}

function fetchItemById(id) {
    const endpoint = `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}.json`
    return fetch(endpoint)
    .then(res => res.json());
}

export function fetchStoryList (type) {
    return fetchStoryIds(type)
    .then(idList => Promise.all(idList.slice(0,50).map(id => fetchItemById(id)));
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to update `fetchStoryList()` so that the final `.then()` returns a promise that is resolved after all promises in the mapped array (ie from `idList.map(..)`) are resolved.

This can be achieved with [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). `Promise.all()` take an array as an input, and will complete after all promises in the supplied array have successfully completed:

```
export function fetchStoryList(type) {

  return fetchStoryIds(type)
    .then((idList) => idList.slice(0,50))
    .then((idList) => {

      /* Pass array of promises from map to Promise.all() */
      return Promise.all(idList.map((id) => {
        return fetchItemById(id)
      });

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!  I really appreciate the help.